# Dynamically create C++ object from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to dynamically create a `C++` object from `QML`. I created a `QObject` derived class named `Car` and exposed it to `QML` using `qmlRegisterType<Car>("org.qtproject.models", 1, 0, "Car");`. Inside `QML` I am able to instantiate a `Car` object like this:

```
Car {
    id : car_1
    carName : "H1"
    carBrand : "Hummer"
    carPrice : 125000
}
```

and then use the `car_1` object and pass it back to `C++` with ease if I need to. But what I would like is to create a `Car` object dynamically in `QML`, so I can pass it back to `C++`.

I tried:

```
MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        component = Qt.createQmlObject("Car { id: car_1; carName : \"H1\"; carBrand : \"Hummer\"; carPrice : 125000; }",
                                       parent, "dynamicSnippet1");

        myCarModel.appendRowFromQml(component);
    }
}
```

but no luck. With the static approach, works fine:

```
MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        myCarModel.appendRowFromQml(car_1);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically create a `C++` object from the `QML` side? I also couldn't use `Qt.createComponent` because there is no `*.qml` file in which `Car` is defined, as `Car` was defined in `C++`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the problem is you need to include `import QtQuick 2.0;` in the string passed to `Qt.createQmlObject`

Comment: @Tarod Thanks for the answer. I also tried `component = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.4; import org.qtproject.models 1.0; Car { id: car_1; carName : \"H1\"; carBrand : \"Hummer\"; carPrice : 125000; }", parent, "dynamicSnippet1");` and I get `qrc:/main.qml:58: Error: Invalid write to global property "component"` when the code gets executed...

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you write `var component = Qt.createQmlObject` instead of `component = Qt.createQmlObject`?

Comment: @Tarod That was the problem. Crap...write an answer so I can accept it :) Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Well, thanks to you! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the problem is the variable `component`, which doesn't exist at that time.

So to fix the problem it is enough to replace the following code:

```
onClicked: {
    component = Qt.createQmlObject(...);
```

by:

```
onClicked: {
    var component = Qt.createQmlObject(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) .

Something like this:

```
Loader {
   id: carLoader
   active: false
   sourceComponent:
   Car {
       id : car_1
       carName : "H1"
       carBrand : "Hummer"
       carPrice : 125000
   } 

MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: carLoader.active:true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually all qml objects are dynamically allocated. In your case `Car` has also. `Loader` and other alternatives are just for directing it over qml. So if you like to pass a qml object on C++ side, the only thing you need to have a slot/invokable function with Car * parameter. In your slot/invokable function, you must specify that you are taking the objects ownership to qml engine.

Suppose you have a Car class something similar like this,

```
class Car : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)

public:
    explicit Car(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~Car();

    QString name();
    void setName(const QString &name);

signals:
    void nameChanged();

private:
    QString m_name;
};
```

And a Store class similar to this,

```
class Store : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Store(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    Q_INVOKABLE void sell(Car *car);
};
```

And if you pass your Car object to Store object on qml,

```
Car {
    id: car1
    name: "H1"
}

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: Store.sell(car1);
}
```

then you must to specify the object ownership in your sell function,

```
void Store::sell(Car *car)
{
    qDebug() << car->name() << "just sold!!";
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(car, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
    delete car; // proof of the car is dynamically allocated
}
```